# How to match URL pattern like /abc?path=xyz in web.xml

Tags: java, regex, servlets, deployment-descriptor

I have a html file at some location in my environment, which I need to restrict from accessing from all users. So I am just trying to add a filter and restrict the html page or to redirect it to another page. Here is the code I am using,

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PageCheckFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.src.filter.PageCheckFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PageCheckFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/app?asset=test&path=/xyz-0.1.2/page.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have tried many URL patterns to match this URL but all in vain. Please suggest me something so that I could restrict this page from accessing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't include query parameters in your filter mapping! According to the [servlet specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/), the URL path used for mapping is the request URL minus context path and parameters (see chapter 12.1 - Use or URL Paths). So the query string is removed from the URL before it is mapped to your pattern.

Even if it were possible to have a query string in your mapping, it would only work if the query parameters are not reordered (e.g. `/app?path=/xyz-0.1.2/page.html&asset=test`).

Instead, you should map your filter to all requests to `/app` and analyze the query parameter within the filter by yourself!

Comment: Yes, that can be done. But don't you think that this will add aextra processing effort to a web application, because by this each and every request will have to go through this filter. right..??

Comment: @Guru Filtering is never a extra pain, If you want to maintain a secure web application :) It's normal that you need proper authorization before you are getting something valuable :)

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing is not the correct way to achieve.

What you can do it write a filter which servers pages on proper Authentication. Write a authentication filter and map all your request to that filter.

So that the filter forwards the request if and only if valid user/client requested the particular page.

For ex: checking the logged in user in session or not.

Look at out Filter tag info, you can find a good example to start with a filter.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info

Comment: Thank you Suresh, One more point to add that this page is inside a framework jar I am using. This HTML page is not added in my web application. The jar contains this page by default and which I don't want to be accessible.

Comment: @Guru  Where ever the resource is when you map the filter with `/*` for filter each request hits the filter and check for authentication. You can even know the URL hit by the client in filter by writing `request.getRequestURL()`

Comment: Thank you again Suresh, There are many other things. As you suggested to use /* or /app pattern to get URl would help me, but these URL patterns are already used in web.xml and processing classes are framework default (we cannot modify these servlets). So using two servlets for single URL pattern is good?? or will mess up the things?

Comment: `So using two servlets for single URL pattern is good??` , You mean servlet or filter ??  If it is filter then no issues you can use multiple filters. No issues in that.